# Uso de LinQ, para obtener valores distintos de una lista con propiedad

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq

Necesito obtener de una lista, los valores que son distintos (**cantidades distintas**) junto con su respectiva descripción. La lista se carga desde un arreglo con un constructor agregando las propiedades “**cantidad**” y “**descripción.**”

```
    public class Proceso
    {
        public int cantidad { get; set; }
        public string descripcion { get; set; }

        public Proceso(int cant, string descp)
        {
            cantidad = cant;
            descripcion = descp;
        }
    }
private static void MetodoSeleccion()       
{
    string[,] arreglo = new string[7, 2];
        arreglo[0, 0] = "10"; arreglo[0, 1] = "descripcion 1";
        arreglo[1, 0] = "15"; arreglo[1, 1] = "descripcion 2";
        arreglo[2, 0] = "7";  arreglo[2, 1] = "descripcion 3";
        arreglo[3, 0] = "7";  arreglo[3, 1] = "descripcion 4";
        arreglo[4, 0] = "60"; arreglo[4, 1] = "descripcion 5";
        arreglo[5, 0] = "95"; arreglo[5, 1] = "descripcion 6";
        arreglo[6, 0] = "60"; arreglo[6, 1] = "descripcion 7";

        List<Proceso> lista = new List<Proceso>();

        int i = 0;
        while (i < arreglo.GetLength(0))
        {
            lista.Add(new Proceso(Convert.ToInt32(arreglo[i, 0]), arreglo[i, 1]));
            i++;
        }

        var cantidades = from item in lista.Distinct()
                         orderby item.cantidad
                         select item;

    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El **operador Distinct** es perfecto para eliminar los duplicados de una colección, si tenemos un **arreglo de enteros** y aplicamos el **operador Distinct**, nos devolverá una nueva colección pero sin los elementos duplicados.

Pero que pasa cuando es un **tipo de datos complejo**, digamos una **lista de Personas**, donde cada persona tiene como propiedades el **Nombre** y la **Edad** de la persona y queremos aplicar el **operador Distinct** para eliminar las personas cuyo nombre es duplicado, o quizá complicarnos un poquito más y eliminar las personas que tienen el mismo nombre y la misma edad, pues entonces las cosas cambian un poquito.

Para resolver este problema debes hacer uso de la **interfaz IEquatable**, un poco de código para que entiendas:

```
public class Proceso : IEquatable<Proceso>
{
    public int cantidad { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }

    public Proceso(int cant, string descp)
    {
        cantidad = cant;
        descripcion = descp;
    }

    public bool Equals(Proceso other)
    {
        //Código
    }
}
```

Siguiendo tu ejemplo decimos que tu **clase Proceso implementará la interfaz IEquatable**. Ahora bien, una interfaz es un tipo de dato abstracto que establece un contrato con nuestra clase y le dirá que métodos debe implementar. En este caso esta interfaz trae como contrato el método:

```
public bool Equals(Proceso other)
{
        
}
```

Este es el método donde pondremos nuestro código. Una interfaz tiene muchísimas utilidades te recomiendo que investigues más sobre ellas, si has usado **Linq** pues te digo que seguramente habrás hecho uso de la interfaz **IEnumerable** o quizás también **IQueryable**.

Implementando el **método Equals**:

```
public bool Equals(Proceso other)
{
    return cantidad == other.cantidad;   
}
```

Este método devolverá **true** si ambos objetos tienen la misma cantidad.

Después habría que sobrescribir el **método GetHashCode**, ya que "alteramos" la condición que establece que dos objetos son iguales(En este caso lo que nos dice que dos objetos son iguales es que tienen la misma cantidad):

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return cantidad.GetHashCode();
}
```

El **método GetHashCode** nos devuelve un número único por cada objeto, digamos que es algo así como la huella dactilar del objeto, que como en el caso de las personas es única.

Y ahora sí podríamos hacer uso del **operador Distinct**:

```
var procesosNoDuplicados = procesos.Distinct().ToList();
```

Cuando vas a implementar la interfaz debes hacer lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te paras con el cursor arriba de la misma y seleccionas la segunda opción como se muestra en la imagen y automáticamente se añade el **método Equals** para que lo implementes, como se muestra en la imagen.

Comment: Excelente me funciono, te debo una.

Answer (score 1):

Hum, está horrible el llenado de la lista pero supongo será una tarea o algo similar dado que para una aplicación de producción no aplica en nada.

Del código mostrado al llamar al método Distinct() sobre la lista se obtiene exactamente la misma lista dado que internamente se comparan objetos y todos serán diferentes.

```
var cantidades = from item in lista.Distinct() //Este Distinct() no tiene efecto
                     orderby item.cantidad
                     select item; //Esto retorna el objeto completo
```

Por otro lado al ejecutar la sentencia

```
select item;
```

Retonará exactamente la misma lista original, es necesario especificar aquí qué propiedad del objeto se desea retornar, para el caso particular: **cantidad**

Para obtener específicamente las cantidades se podría invocar de la siguiente forma:

```
var cantidades = (from item in lista
                orderby item.cantidad
                select item.cantidad).Distinct();//Aplicar el Distinct al resultado de la selección
```

Comment: El llenado de la lista, es solo un ejemplo, lo hice de esta manera para simplificar la consulta para ahorrar palabras e ir directo al grano, es un proyecto que estoy desarrollando personalmente. Gracias por la ayuda me funciono, ahora comprendo un poco mas de LinQ. Saludos.

Comment: La respuesta está bien, pero solo si se selecciona a la propiedad cantidad.Si tuvieras que seleccionar las dos propiedades no funcionaría

Comment: @Ariel, lee el comentario de arriba

Comment: @Japv, es cierto lo que mencionas, y en realidad es lo que necesito, creo que no plantee bien la consulta (el código de ejemplo), en una hora aproximadamente modificare la consulta.

Comment: @Japv excelente explicación, aplicar la interfaz de la forma mencionada hace que el primer `Distinct()` funcione correctamente, requerirá un poco más de código pero hará que las consultas posteriores se simplifiquen.