# ¿Cómo podría agrupa los items repetidos de una lista en c#?

Tags: c#, array, api, asp.net-core

Tengo una lista con estos datos, hay alguna manera de agrupar los elementos repetidos,
y que los turnos se agrupen al item repetido

```
{
   "id_curso": 1,
   "nombre_curso": "Matematica",
   "id_turno": 20,
   "nombre_turno": "Mañana",
},
{
   "id_curso": 1,
   "nombre_curso": "Matematica",
   "id_turno": 21,
   "nombre_turno": "tarde",
},
{
   "id_curso": 2,
   "nombre_curso": "Comunicacion",
   "id_turno": 15,
   "nombre_turno": "Mañana",
},
```

Este seria el resultado que quiero obtener utilizando codigo c#

```
{
   "id_curso": 1,
   "nombre_curso": "Matematica",
   "turnos": [
      {
         "id_turno": 20,
         "nombre_turno": "Mañana"
      },
      {
         "id_turno": 21,
         "nombre_turno": "Tarde"
      },
   ],
},
```

Comment: Tendrias que hacer una lista nueva, porque tiene otra estructura y usar linq para hacer un group by

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/435330/uso-de-linq-para-obtener-valores-distintos-de-una-lista-con-propiedad/435458#435458, revisa esta respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Hola quizá llego un poco tarde como para que la respuesta ayude, pero tal vez sirve a alguien más.

La respuesta a tu solicitud esta clara, necesitas **Agrupar** los items (cursos) repetidos y que los turnos asignados a dicho item pasen a su curso correspondiente, la respuesta está en el mismo problema.

Ahora bien, los grupos se generan por elementos coincidentes o que comparten algo en común, por ejemplo en tu caso el curso **matemática** en esta sección

```
{
   "id_curso": 1,
   "nombre_curso": "Matematica",
   "id_turno": 20,
   "nombre_turno": "Mañana",
},
{
   "id_curso": 1,
   "nombre_curso": "Matematica",
   "id_turno": 21,
   "nombre_turno": "tarde",
}
```

Se observa que es el mismo grupo (por obviedad) sin embargo ¿Qué comparten en común? Puede ser el **id_curso**, el **nombre_curso** o ambos. Teniendo claro esto, solo debemos hacer el código, que usando LINQ podría ser algo como:

```
var cursosYTurnos = ObtenerCursos(); // Tu lista de cursos deberia estar acá

// Agrupamos los cursos por Id y los transformamos a la nueva clase
var cursos = cursosYTurnos.GroupBy(ct => ct.IdCurso).Select(grp => new Curso(){
    IdCurso = grp.Key,
    NombreCurso = grp.Max(ct => ct.NombreCurso),
    // Convertimos los datos del turno a una lista de un nuevo objeto.
    Turnos = grp.Select(ct => new Turno(){
        IdTurno = ct.IdTurno,
        NombreTurno = ct.NombreTurno
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Resultado:

[image: Resultado ejecucion]

El método `GroupBy()` te permite agrupar los elementos de una colección, en este caso los cursos, y el elemento que se decide utilizar para la agrupación es el **IdCurso**, el método **GroupBy** te devuelve una Interfaz que es el grupo como tal (note la variable **grp**), luego solo usamos algunos métodos de agregación más (no se detallara eso) para recuperar los demás datos utilizando el método `Select()` que "transforma" una lista de una forma a otra forma.

Por último para los turnos, a partir de la agrupación (variable **grp** devuelta por **GroupBy**) seleccionamos los datos del turno de cada curso que estaba en el listado anterior y lo transformamos en un nuevo objeto de **Turno** que solamente tiene su Id y su nombre.

Puede ver el código completo de la solución aquí:

[image: Imagen]

[Codigo completo](https://replit.com/@Brandon-ManuelM/ItemsGroup)